# Why does it not change when I make changes to the py folder in exe that I created using cx_freeze in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, cx-freeze

I converted the python file to exe with cx_freeze. The following is the setup.py file. When I run hello.exe, the output is like this. 'Hello Brother !!!' 
but when I change the "Good morning" in hi.py file and run hello.exe, "Hello brother !!!" It appears.
What should I do in the setup file to make changes to hi.py after creating exe for this?

`setup.py`

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup(name="hello",
      version="0.1",
      description="hellov1",
      executables=[Executable("hello.py")],
      )
```

`hi.py`

```
print("Hello Brother!!!")
```

`hello.py`

```
import cx_Freeze
import hi
```

Answer (score 0):

Because .py files will become exe will be a little complicated to edit it (if not impossible). But instead of that **hi.py** try to make your own data file. Basically is just a text file so is easy. And that be sad data base will be out of code and can be edited easy after and changes will affect your code dinamicaly.

**hello.py** will look like this:

```py
#import cx_Freeze #// I do not know what this do. You know
from hi import DataBase, Logic

# Make shore that base is take it
DataBase.GetDataBase()
# Now make shore to import data base library updated
from hi import dataBaseLib

# Hello message
Logic.Hello(dataBaseLib["hello_message"])
```

**hi.py** will look like this:

```py
dataBaseFile = "custom_data.kmb_bey"
dataBaseLib = {}

class Logic:
    def Hello(msg):
        print(msg)

class DataBase:
    def GetDataBase(fileName=dataBaseFile):
        try:
            DataBase.ReadFile(fileName)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            DataBase.WriteFile(fileName)
            DataBase.ReadFile(fileName)
    
    def WriteFile(fileName):
        with open(fileName, "w") as file:
            file.write("""#// Custom Data Base for KMB_Bey
hello_message=Hello Brother!!!""")

    def ReadFile(fileName):
        with open(fileName, "r") as file:
            line = file.readline().strip()
            
            while line:
                if line.startswith("#") or line == "":
                    line = file.readline().strip()
                elif "=" in line:
                    x = line.split("=")
                    data, info = x[0].strip(), x[1].strip()
                    if data not in dataBaseLib.keys():
                        dataBaseLib[data] = info
                line = file.readline().strip()
```

That bee sad, does no matter if the file *custom_data.kmb_bey* exist or not, will be created if is not existing and that file you can change it with any text editor. What you will type there will populate your data base if **=** is on that line. What you will type before equal sign become the key of the data and what you type after the equal sign becomes the value. For the example in `user name = Jhonny` data base will have a "user name" as a key (on code example I name it "data") and "Jhonny" as a value (on code example I name it "info".

I hope the code will help you. I just write it directly on browser web on my phone from my head. I do not test it yet. But I'm shore will work 90%.